# Dynamically change TPL Dataflow Block MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

When I create a Dataflow Block I specify its `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` like this:

```
...New ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions With 
   {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount - 1}...
```

Is any way to change it later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

What you can do is to create the block with a high enough MDOP (possibly `Unbounded`) and use [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim) to limit the degree of parallelism to what you actually want.

Then, when you want to change the degree of parallelism, call `Release(int releaseCount)` (to increase it) or `await WaitAsync()` in a loop (to decrease it).

Comment: Would you still want to use Dataflow Block with this?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't change the degree while using the same block.

But, you can set it to a higher number from the start and it will only use as much as it needs (hence `Max`).

Or you could create a new block with a higher `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and start posting your items to it while waiting for the old block to finish.