# Background parallel process of SQL queries in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, npgsql

I'm working on a small C# tool that processes lot of SQL statements.

The GUI features tools to generate and display a queue of SQL statements. I want to process them in parallel, control the maximum number of parallel queries on the fly (when reduced).

- Some SQL queries return result sets.
- It must spawn just the one connexion per worker and reuse them for next task
- It must be able to pause/restart the processing of the queue gracefully
- It must support increase/decrease the number of simultaneous tasks while processing
- The GUI shows the current progress (the list of what is running)
- I would rather use Tasks (single physical thread) instead of threads

What is the best way to do it ?

I found several questions about parallel workers, but no answer shows how to report progress.

Comment: You can specify a max degree of parrellism using a [`Parrell.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop). I'd start there. I'd imagine this is a duplicate but this question is pretty vague/broad

Comment: google connection pooling

Comment: What database engine are you using? Are you sure your queue will actually improve things, compared with running queries asynchronously and letting the database engine deal with processing queries as efficiently as possible?

Comment: @JonasH It will be either postgres or Oracle. I want to master and adjust how many queries are currently running.

Comment: @bokan About: "The GUI shows the current progress (the list of what is running)"- 
So far as i know BackgroundWorker (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=net-6.0)  has ability to report progress, and it is working on another thread. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: about "I want to spawn just the right amount of connexions and reuse them"- you could implement "Factory" pattern that manages connections and reuse them. You can read about it here: https://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

Comment: Some related questions: [Is it possible to change parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism during execution of a Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705006/is-it-possible-to-change-paralleloptions-maxdegreeofparallelism-during-execution) / [How to dynamically control Parallelism Degree based on object sizes (or some system constraints)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744296/how-to-dynamically-control-parallelism-degree-based-on-object-sizes-or-some-sys) / [Dynamically change TPL Dataflow Block .MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441338)